# `ngClass` directive apply class as `object` instead of `class` value

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular8

I am applying the class name as follows:

`<tr *ngIf="crud.isCreate" [ngClass]="{'create' : curd?.isCreate}">`

but I am not class name added with it. in html it shows like:

`<tr _ngcontent-yql-c9="" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">` - what is wrong here?

`*ngIf="crud.isCreate"` - condition works properly.

any one help me to understand?

Comment: What is the value of `curd` ?

Comment: Do you mean to have `curd?.isCreate` or should it be `crud?.isCreate`?

Comment: You seem to have a typo in your code. The ````ngIf```` is using the ````crud```` object while the ````ngClass```` uses ````curd````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo there. `curd` should be `crud`

```
<tr *ngIf="crud.isCreate" [ngClass]="{'create' : crud?.isCreate}">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this.
I'm considering no typo in your code.

```
<tr *ngIf="crud.isCreate" [ngClass]="curd?.isCreate ? 'create' : ''">
```

I hope it helps you out